# Jaxb/JSON reponse with field containing existing JSON array

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, marshalling

I have a pojo with a field that contains JSON array and jaxb wraps this data as a string
is there any way to overcome this problem without umarshalling and marshalling the json content and without using a custom message writer? or ca i define a custom writer in a field with some annotation?

```
@XmlRootElement
public class TestPojo{
   String name;
   String list;
   @XmlElement(name="name")    
   public String getName(){
       return this.name;
   }
   @XmlElement(name="data")
   public String getData(){
       return this.data;
   }

}
```

data is an existing json array in string format

so i want to expose it as JSON

```
{
 "name":"My Name",
 "data":[{"el":"aname"}, {"el":"aname2"}]
}
```

Instead of

```
    "data":"[{"el":"aname"}, {"el":"aname2"}]"
```

Comment: Please, add a code snippet to your question.

Comment: added some example code and json output

Comment: you are trying to get jaxb to parse json?

Comment: no i am trying to find a simple way to represent in jaxb existing xml or json data (in string format) without marshalling/unmarshalling the data